# lists and sublists

Tags: python

say i have an output of this, i think its a list

```
['', 'AB-a-b-c-d', 'BC-f-c-a-r', 'CD-i-s-r']
```

i want to make the following:

```
['',[AB,a,b,c,d],[BC,f,c,a,r],[CD,i,s,r]]
```

or

```
['',[AB,BC,CD],[a,b,c,d],[f,c,a,r],[i,s,r]]
```

Comment: Which bits do you need help with? Splitting the dash-separated strings into a list, doing it inside another list or extracting the first items from each sublist into another list?

Comment: what's up with the empty string?

Comment: say i cant do this
i want to get this
[[a,b,c,d],[f,c,a,r],[i,s,r]]
from that list so that i can later assign each sublist to to individual list, so that i can chose a index randomly from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
newlist = [item.split("-") for item in oldlist]
```

or (this works better because the empty string is kept as is)

```
newlist = []
for item in oldlist:
    if not item:
        newlist.append(item)
    else:
        newlist.append(item.split("-"))
```

Comment: i get the following:
[[AB,e,r,t,y,],[BC,h,d,n,q],[CD,k,r,o]]
how can i print only AB

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to point you in the right direction rather than solve your homework for you: Try [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and some for loops.