# How to slice a list into sublists that exist within a new list

Tags: python, list

For example I have a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and I want to make a new list in which I nest its elements into another list so that it becomes [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
How can I do this?

More example:
long_string= "String literals are written in single or double quotes: 'xyzzy', 'frobozz'. See String literals for more about string literals. Unicode strings are much like strings, but are specified in the syntax using a preceding 'u' character: u'abc', u'def'. In addition to the functionality described here, there are also string-specific methods described in the String Methods section. Lists are constructed with square brackets, separating items with commas: [a, b, c]. Tuples are constructed by the comma operator (not within square brackets), with or without enclosing parentheses, but an empty tuple must have the enclosing parentheses, such as a, b, c or (). A single item tuple must have a trailing comma, such as (d,)."

c=long_string.split(',')

After this, I want to arrange c by dividing the split elements into many other lists

Comment: What's the criteria for nesting?

Comment: the question is clear. How can I make the first list become the second list?

Comment: I see many users with high reputation here just try to vote down questions of new users

Comment: @user3670684 May be because, most of us cannot figure out how the first list becomes the second list?

Comment: No... you aren't telling anyone how you determine how to split the list into smaller lists.  Your example shows 2 items, then 3, then 3.  Is that all you want to do? 2, 3, 3?

Comment: I have no idea how I would apply your first to second list if for example we decided to try it with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b,' 'c', 'd', 'e']`. What does that map to? You need to say exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't know how to change the first list into the second list by using python so I ask for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [lists and sublists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215045/lists-and-sublists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then, here is how you could do exactly that using slicing.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = []
b.append(a[0:2])
b.append(a[2:5])
b.append(a[5:9])
```

Comment: @woot I believe we shouldn't encourage the questions which are not so clear.

Comment: @thefourtheye Oddly, that's all he was looking for, so I guess it was sort of clear.  I have no idea why he wants to slice it this way, though.

Comment: @thefourtheye - I think it was pretty clear what the OP was asking.  Can't say I understand the WHY, but does that really matter?  Ask a question, receive an answer.

Comment: @miR I think it has to do with the fact that he said it was an example. "For example..." makes one think that this is just a case amongst many, so we all assumed there were other cases, but this one case didn't tell us enough to generalize.

Comment: @woot how can I solve it without using append() every time? Because the list is actually very long, unlike the sample. Please help

Comment: This is where you would need to tell us more about what it is you are actually trying to do.  There is no rhyme or reason behind what you asked for, only a very specific question.  What pattern are you looking for in dividing the list?  Why are you dividing the list in the first place?

Comment: @woot I want to arrange the string into a neat list by dividing the split elements into many other lists

Comment: For printing purposes?  A neat list in memory doesn't really serve any purposes and there are better ways to print it nicely.

Comment: no, it is to build a social network by arranging big data.

Comment: @woot  I think you can help

Comment: Look up doing something like `for it in range(0,len(s)):` I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out where to stick `it`.